Questions about the conditional expected value.
I am learning about the conditional expected value and have a few questions. My Questions are regarding the following two definitions.
Definition 1:
Let $X,Y$ be two random variables.
The conditional expected value $E[X|Y]$ is the random variable which takes the value $E[X|Y=y]$, when $Y(\omega)=y$, i.e.
$E[X|Y]=\sum_y E[X|Y=y] \cdot \mathbb{1}_{{Y=y}}$.
Definition 2:
Let $G=\sigma(A_1,A_2,...)$ where $A_1,A_2,...$  is a finite or countable partition of $\Omega$. Then we define
$E[X|G]:= \sum_i 1_{A_i} E[X|A_i]$.
Note that $E[X|Y]=E[X|\sigma(Y)]$.
Question 1:
In Definition 1, it is said that we consider $E[X|Y]$ to be a random variable, lets call it $Z$.
And we calculate the value of $Z$ by summation of the "individual" expected values for every $y$ that $Y$ takes as value. But then we would get a value $\in \mathbb{R}$ for $Z$. But if $Z$ is a random variable it should be a function, not a value.
Whats the deal with $E[X|Y]$?
Question 2:
In Definition 2 we consider a partition of $\Omega$ into $A_1,A_2,...$. Then we define the sigma-algebra $G$ to be the smallest sigma algebra containing said partition of $\Omega$.
Then we again sum the "individual" expected values to get $E[X|G]$. What is the reason for this kind of construction?
Question 3:
After the Definition 2, it is mentioned that $E[X|Y]=E[X|\sigma(Y)]$. But $\sigma(Y)$ is not defined. Could someone explain to me why $E[X|Y]=E[X|\sigma(Y)]$ (and how one gets to the result)?

Your definition 1 (for when $Y$ is discrete) is in fact a weighted sum of random variables (not a constant) because $1_{Y=y}$ is a Bernoulli random variable that can be either 0 or 1 depending on $Y$ (it is a function of $Y$). Definition 2 can be viewed as the same as def 1 by defining $Y=i$ iff $X\in A_i$.

The $\sigma(Y)$ is defined as "the sigma algebra generated by random variable $Y$," which for discrete random variables $Y$ is the same as the sigma algebra corresponding to the partition $A_1 ,A_2, A_3, ...$ where $A_1={Y=y_1}$, $A_2={Y=y_2}$, $A_3 = {Y=y_3}$ and so on.

@Michael I do not understand why $E[X|Y]$ should be a wighted sum of random variables. My thought was $E[X|Y]:=\sum_y E[X|Y=y] 1_{Y=y}= \sum_y ( \sum_x x \frac{P(X=x,Y=y)}{P(Y=y)} ) \cdot 1_{Y=y}$, and thus I did get a constant.

Your definition is itself a weighted sum of Bernoulli random variables. So $E[X|Y]=E[X|Y=y_1]$ if $Y=y_1$, $E[X|Y]=E[X|Y=y_2]$ if $Y=y_2$, and so on. So its value is not fixed, it depends on the random variable $Y$. That is, $E[X|Y]=f(Y)$ for some (measurable) function $f$.

@Michael Oh, I thought $1_{Y=y}$ was the indicator function. But now it starts to make sense.
